# Changing a DataContext ConnectionTimeout does not affect the observable timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a [`System.Data.Linq.DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) object with the [`ConnectionTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) property set to 1 second but the connection is still taking 30 seconds to return an exception.

Here is the code with the StopWatch output to show the issue:

```
Debug.WriteLine("!! Method start");
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

MyDataClassesDataContext dc = new MyDataClassesDataContext();

Debug.WriteLine("!! Connection.ConnectionTimeout is: " + dc.Connection.ConnectionTimeout);
// Output is: !! Connection.ConnectionTimeout is: 1

Debug.WriteLine("!! CommandTimeout is: " + dc.CommandTimeout);
// Output is: !! CommandTimeout is: 1

try
{
    string s = (from rows in dc.MyTable
                where rows.MyValue == 3
                select rows.MySecondValue).SingleOrDefault();

    return s;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("!! Method ended after " + sw.Elapsed.Seconds + " seconds");
    // Output is: !! Method ended after 27 seconds

    return null;
}
```

The [`ConnectionTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) property was set to 1 using a connection string. It appears to be 1 before connecting so it should timeout after 1 second but instead takes 27 seconds. Is this the wrong timeout value to modify when using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: I deleted my answer as I thought this was EF (I should look at the tags more). Where are you setting your command timeout in your DataContext ?

Comment: I do this in the OnCreated Method:
partial void OnCreated()
{
 this.CommandTimeout = 1;
}

Comment: Is the exception related to the Connection? Because that would be the `ConnectionTimeout` that you'd need to change (I know it's obvious, just need to know).

Comment: Yes, the exception is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found

Comment: You set the `CommandTimeout` to 1, but there is no command sent. The waiting time is related to the `ConnectionTimeout` (which by default is 30, I believe).

Comment: Ok, I've removed the CommandTimeout, so it's just the ConnectionTimeout=1 that is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between `ConnectionTimeout`, which specifies how long to wait when trying to connect to the Sql server before giving up, and the `CommandTimeout`, which specifies how long to wait for a command/query to run before giving up. Try setting the `CommandTimeout` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout.aspx

Comment: I tried setting the `CommandTimeout` to 1 as well (it was in the initial version of this posted question) but I removed it as another commenter pointed out that there is no command sent.

Comment: Why do you think there is no command sent? How else will you get the query to execute on the server?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I've added the `CommandTimeout` part back into the sample code.

Comment: So, does it work? Could you please write out the exception, instead of just swallowing it? It might help you to understand what is happening.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it still takes 27 seconds. I posted the exception in the comments in the previous section.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Missed that one. So, the exception is obviously related to connecting, yes. Although it doesn't seem trivial to control this on a network level. There's an article on the subject here: http://improve.dk/controlling-sqlconnection-timeouts/